# Lead and Lag Partitioning Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table with three columns http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbfb8/1

```
create table xx ( id number, stn number , str varchar2(20));

insert into xx (id,stn) values (1,2001);
insert into xx (id,stn) values (2,2002);
insert into xx (id,stn) values (3,2003);
insert into xx (id,stn) values (4,2004);
insert into xx (id,stn) values (1,3001);
insert into xx (id,stn) values (2,3002);
insert into xx (id,stn) values (3,3003);
```

for the third column str the values should be

```
2001 - 
2001 - 2002
2002 - 2003
2003 - 2004
3001 - 
3001 - 3002 
3002 - 3003
```

What should be my partition column. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is unclear.  The following comes pretty close to what you want using `lag()`:

```
select xx.*,
       (lag(stn) over (partition by trunc(stn / 1000) order by id) ||
        ' - ' || stn
       ) as str
from xx;
```

I can't figure out why you would want "2001 - " instead of " - 2001" for the first row.

Comment: trunc(stn/1000) ? , The stn values in real table are different like 204079, 205016 etc. Its not working for values like those. The stn values are not sequential.

Comment: @user2653353 . . . That is a reasonable interpretation of the data you provided in the question.